# ASP.net webhost with owin self host throws "silent" exception on Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a ASP.net webapi that Im hosting with OWIN selfhost when Im testing it. 
Im having it write to console on requests to see what its up to. 
However after a while (10 requests or so) it stops working property. 
When I debug it I find that when its invoking my Console. WriteLine it just exits no exception no nothing. 
I've checked that there are no null values the properties going into the WriteLine-method.
Here is the code for one of the failing endpoints:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBatchPackage()
    {
        var document = Program.NDTServerSession.GetNextNDTDocument(DateTime.Now);
        if (document == null)
            return Ok();

        var batchOperation = document.GetNextBatchOperation();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Document requested: {document.CentralFilePath}. Batch Operation id: {batchOperation?.BatchOperationInfoId} ");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Caught exception in GetBatchPackage");
        }

        return Ok(document);


    }
```

If there is an exception thrown in the first Console.WriteLine its not being caught in the exception handler. 
Can you turn exceptions on?

Thanks!

EDIT 1: I have visual studio break an all CLR Exceptions, no difference.

EDIT 2: I've started passing the Console.Writeline a string reference (I dont create the string inside the method with parameters, to ensure that I dont have any problems with the parameters in my strint interpolation). No difference. All the strings I've looked at work.

Comment: could it be taht `Console.WriteLine` is throwing?

Comment: Yes, that was my idea, but how can I catch that exception? 
When I debug it I cant catch it! The thread just exists at the first Console.WriteLine